# Get/Create list of Integration Keys available in DocuSign using docusignapi

Tags: api, docusignapi

I was going through the **DocuSign** REST API's(docusignapi), but didn't come across any API which will get me the list of Integration API keys available in the specified Account.
My requirement is to display the list of API Integration keys available if there aren't any then Create a new using the data required to generate an API Integration key.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your use case? Why do you want to do this? Also remember that all integration keys are created in demo. They are only available in production after the GoLive process has been completed.

Comment: We have an account for sandbox which has many Integration Keys available around >100, so we were planning to provide an interface to users where we will list down all the Integration keys which are not expired, and if there are no keys then it will create one through API, once the key is selected we will configure the Connect configuration using the API, in short we were trying to ignore manual steps to Login into the Sandbox environment, creating an API key, and creating a custom configuration.Note: API key page takes too much time to load all available API keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have a public/documented API to enable developers to get the list of Integration Keys at this time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some miscommunication here:

> We have an account for sandbox which has many Integration Keys available around >100, so we were planning to provide an interface to users where we will list down all the Integration keys which are not expired, and if there are no keys then it will create one through API, once the key is selected we will configure the Connect configuration using the API, in short we were trying to ignore manual steps to Login into the Sandbox environment, creating an API key, and creating a custom configuration.

- Integration Keys (also known as client_ids) do not expire.
- Integration Keys are used one per application. I don't know of a reason why 
  an application would need more than one IK. Why do you have > 100 IKs?
- Integration Keys are used (via OAuth) to obtain access keys. If the OAuth Authorization Grant flow is used then a refresh token is also created.
- Access Tokens do expire.
- Creating/refreshing an Access Token depends on how you created it:

  Authorization Code Grant: use the refresh token or have the user authenticate again.

  Implicit Grant: the user must authenticate again.

  JWT Grant: re-do the JWT Grant flow to obtain a new access token.

### Added

From the comment, it sounds like the issue might be that the applications' access tokens are expiring and the desire is automatically refresh them.

That can be done for access tokens received via the authorization code grant flow by using the refresh token. This can be done as a batch process, but your applications must maintain their own record of the access tokens, the matching refresh tokens, and expiration times.

This type of information not available via any API since it would be a security hole if it were available. Your app(s) must store this information.

Comment: Its "Renew Expired" and not "Expired", sorry for the not mentioning exact word. And we have multiple keys for respective applications, they are not all for the same app. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @TAUFEEQATTAR I added to my answer